# AWK Output Produces Function Not Defined

Tags: awk

I inherited this code so I'm seeing if someone can help me with the error message.

Here's the AWK file.  This file uses a CSV file and is supposed to produce a formatted list.

The return error is FNR=1 fatal: function `header' not defined.

This must have worked at some point in time.  Not sure how long it's been broken and I just learned about it a couple of days ago.

Can anyone help?

CSV File

```
"POSN","STATUS","TITLE","BEGIN_DATE","END_DATE","ROLL","PIDM","A_NUMBER","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","EGRP"
"C99999","A","Title","01-JUL-95","","C",888888,"A00888888","John","Doe1","22"
"C99999","A","Ttile","01-JUL-95","","C",9999999,"A09999999","John","Doe2","23"
"C11111","A","Title","01-JUL-95","","C",0000001,"A00000001","John","Doe3","01"
```

$PROG_LC.awk

```
# fieldname    len
#  1 posn        6
#  2 status      1
#  3 title      30
#  4 begin_date 10
#  5 end_date   10
#  6 roll        1
#  7 a_number    8
#  8 a_number    9
#  9 first_name 15
# 10 last_name  30
# 11 egrp        4

BEGIN { pagelen = 20; pagewidth = 126
        lenheader = 4; lendetail = 1; lenfooter = 2 }

header() {
    print trititle("XXXXXXX", "Report",
          sprintf("Page %d", pagenum))
    print ""
    print " Posn  S Title                          Begin Date  End Date  " \
          "R A-Number  First Name      Last Name                      Egrp"
    print "------ - ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- " \
          "- -------- --------- --------------- ------------------------------ ----" }

detail(X) {
    printf "%-6.6s %-1.1s %-30.30s %-10.10s %-10.10s %-1.1s %-8.8s %-9.9s " \
           "%-15.15s %-30.30s %-4.4s\n", X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5],
           X[6], X[7], X[8], X[9], X[10], X[11] }

footer() { print ""; print trititle(user "@" sid, one_up, today) }
```

Shell Script

```
#!/bin/sh

. $BANNER_HOME/local/exe/local_init.sh

H=/home/jobsub/${ORACLE_SID}_LOGS
PROG_LC=`echo $PROG | tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]"`
PROG_UC=`echo $PROG | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]"`
CSV=$H/$(basename $PROG_LC .shl)_${ONE_UP}.csv
LOG=$H/$(basename $PROG_LC .shl)_${ONE_UP}.log
WHOAMI=$(whoami)

echo "BANUID     = $BANUID"     >> $LOG
echo "ONE_UP     = $ONE_UP"     >> $LOG
echo "PROG       = $PROG"       >> $LOG
echo "PRNT       = $PRNT"       >> $LOG
echo "ORACLE_SID = $ORACLE_SID" >> $LOG
echo "H          = $H"          >> $LOG
echo "PROG_LC    = $PROG_LC"    >> $LOG
echo "PROG_UC    = $PROG_UC"    >> $LOG
echo "CSV        = $CSV"        >> $LOG
echo "LOG        = $LOG"        >> $LOG
echo "WHOAMI     = $WHOAMI"     >> $LOG
echo "LOCAL_EXE  = $LOCAL_EXE"  >> $LOG

sqlplus -s $BAN9UID/@${TARGETDB} <<EOF
variable status number
begin :status := storedprocs.write_csv_file('$PROG_LC', $ONE_UP);
end;
/
exit :status
EOF

STATUS="$?"
echo "RETURN CODE = $STATUS" >> $LOG

if [ $STATUS -eq 0 ]
then echo "$PROG_UC completed successfully" >> $LOG
else echo "$PROG_UC completed with failure" >> $LOG
fi

if [ -f $LOCAL_EXE/$PROG_LC.awk ]
then LIS=$H/$(basename $PROG_LC .shl)_${ONE_UP}.lis
     LC_NUMERIC=en_US.utf8 gawk -f $LOCAL_EXE/csvtolis.awk \
         -f $LOCAL_EXE/$PROG_LC.awk $CSV > $LIS
     gurinso -n $ONE_UP -l $LIS -j $PROG -w $BANUID $BAN9UID/@${TARGETDB}
fi

exit $STATUS
```

csvtolis.awk

```
BEGIN { linenum = 0 
        pagenum = 0 
        user = toupper(ENVIRON["BAN9UID"]) 
        sid = ENVIRON["ORACLE_SID"] 
        oneup = ENVIRON["ONE_UP"] 
        "date +%m/%d/%Y" | getline today } 

function csvsplit(str, arr,     i,j,n,s,fs,qt) {
    # split comma-separated fields into arr; return number of fields in arr
    # fields surrounded by double-quotes may contain commas;
    #     doubled double-quotes represent a single embedded quote
    delete arr; s = "START"; n = 0; fs = ","; qt = "\""
    for (i = 1; i <= length(str); i++) {
        if (s == "START") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) { arr[++n] = "" }
            else if (substr(str,i,1) == qt) { j = i+1; s = "INQUOTES" }
            else { j = i; s = "INFIELD" } }
        else if (s == "INFIELD") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) {
                arr[++n] = substr(str,j,i-j); j = 0; s = "START" } }
        else if (s == "INQUOTES") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == qt) { s = "MAYBEDOUBLE" } }
        else if (s == "MAYBEDOUBLE") {
            if (substr(str,i,1) == fs) {
                arr[++n] = substr(str,j,i-j-1)
                gsub(qt qt, qt, arr[n]); j = 0; s = "START" } } }
    if (s == "INFIELD" || s == "INQUOTES") { arr[++n] = substr(str,j) }
    else if (s == "MAYBEDOUBLE") {
        arr[++n] = substr(str,j,length(str)-j); gsub(qt qt, qt, arr[n]) }
    else if (s == "START") { arr[++n] = "" }
    return n }

function trititle(left, center, right,     gap1, gap2) { # assume sufficient space
    gap1 = int((pagewidth - length(center)) / 2) - length(left)
    gap2 = pagewidth - length(left) - length(center) - length(right) - gap1
    return left sprintf("%*s", gap1, "") center sprintf("%*s", gap2, "") right }

NR > 1 { nfields = csvsplit($0, csv); # print one record, with header/footer as needed
  if (pagelen - (linenum % pagelen) - lenfooter < lendetail) {
      while ((linenum + lenfooter) % pagelen != 0) { print ""; linenum++ }
      footer(); linenum += lenfooter }
  if (linenum % pagelen == 0) { pagenum++; header(); linenum += lenheader }
  detail(csv); linenum += lendetail
  if ((linenum + lenfooter) % pagelen == 0) { footer(); linenum += lenfooter } }

END { if (linenum % pagelen != 0) {                      # if not at top of page
          while ((linenum + lenfooter) % pagelen != 0) { # while not at bottom
              print ""; linenum++ }                      # skip to bottom
          footer() } }                                   # and print footer
```

Comment: to define a function: `function header() {...}`; to call a function: `header()`; net result: someone removed the word `function` from in front of 3x function definitions; 'course, the next (big) issue is that you've got 3 functions defined but nowhere do you reference them so ... can't tell if you've left out some code or this is a useless `awk` script

Comment: No code was left out.  You are seeing what I'm seeing in the file.  That's how it is and what I have to work with.  Is there an easy way to fix it?  Add "function" and then some call to call that function.

Comment: on the other hand they could be valid function calls but then you're missing the function definitions; is this all of your `awk` code? how is the script invoked? do you by any chance invoke multiple `awk` scripts at once (eg, one contains function definitions, one contains the body of code that processes individual rows, etc)?

Comment: there's a lot more missing from the code you've provided ... nowhere is the `X` array populated, references to variables that are never populated (eg, `pagenum`, `sid`, `one_up`, `today`),  and it looks like you're also missing the definition of a function `trititle()`; based on your comment I'm starting to think there may be other files (containing snippets of `awk` code) that are being combined with this file ... in which case we'd need to see how `awk` is being invoked (eg, `awk -f functions.awk -f logic_1.awk -f logic_2.awk datafile1 datafile2 ... datafileN`)

Comment: Which awk file did you show us, `$LOCAL_EXE/csvtolis.awk` or `$LOCAL_EXE/$PROG_LC.awk`?

Comment: I updated my post with the shell script.   I need to look in the local_init.sh to see if there's some reference to AWK.  Other than that, I don't know where to look.

Comment: $LOCAL_EXE/$PROG_LC.awk

Comment: Ah, I see.  There's the csvtolis.awk file that contains what markp-fuso was talking about.  I'll add that to the post.

Comment: I haven't gone through all of the new code in detail but at this point it looks like you may just need to add the `function` keyword in `$PROG_LC.awk` before the 3x function names, ie, `function header()`, `function detail(X)` and `function footer()`; those 3x edits should get rid of the current error; of related interest ... the 2x function definitions in `csvtolis.awk` are actually coded correctly, ie, `function csvsplit(str, arr, ...)` and `function trititle(left, center, right, ...)`

Comment: with some shells (eg, `bash`) it's possible to define functions with or without the `function` keyword, while in `awk` the `function` keyword is a requirement; I'm wondering if someone edited `$PROG_LC.awk` and erroneously removed the `function` keyword thinking they could apply shell (`bash`?) syntax ... *shrug*

Comment: I'll add the function keyword to the $PROG_LC.awk file and see what happens.  Can't hurt anything at this point.

Comment: Thank you markp-fuso.  That fixed it.  I'm starting to think this process has never worked from day one.  I have no proof on that but until a few days ago, no one has ever looked to see if the file ever contained any data.

Answer (score 0):

I added the function keyword to the $PROG_LC.awk file and that resolved my issue.  This was suggested by markp-fuso and was the solution I needed to get this to work.

I added the keyword "function" in front of "trititle()" so it now became "function trititle()".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).